# How to set heap memory in cassandra on docker

Tags: docker, memory-management, cassandra

I am using a Cassandra docker (official Cassandra docker) to setup my local env.
As part of this I want to limit the amount of memory the Cassandra is using in my local deployment.
By default Cassandra has a pre defined way to set its memory.
I found references to some info saying that i can use JVM_OPTS to set this values but it does not seem to take hold.
I am looking for a way to set up this values without creating my own Cassandra docker.

Docker command that is used to run container:

```
docker run -dit --name sdc-cs --env RELEASE="${RELEASE}" \
   --env CS_PASSWORD="${CS_PASSWORD}" --env ENVNAME="${DEP_ENV}" \
   --env HOST_IP=${IP} --env JVM_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m" \
   --log-driver=json-file --log-opt max-size=100m \
   --log-opt max-file=10 --ulimit memlock=-1:-1 --ulimit nofile=4096:100000 \
   --volume /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro \
   --volume ${WORKSPACE}/data/CS:/var/lib/cassandra \
   --volume ${WORKSPACE}/data/environments:/root/chef-solo/environments \
   --publish 9042:9042 --publish 9160:9160 \
   ${PREFIX}/sdc-cassandra:${RELEASE} /bin/s
```

Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 16):

I am using docker-compose, in the **docker-compose.yml** file I set the following env variables. It seems to work.

```
environment:
    - HEAP_NEWSIZE=128M
    - MAX_HEAP_SIZE=2048M
```

Comment: where can I check if this env variables are taken by cassandra?

Comment: Hi @jhuamanchumo,  `docker exec -it cas1 bash -c 'echo $MAX_HEAP_SIZE'`  
result: `1024M` . `cas1` indicates the container name.

Answer (score 6):

Entrypoint script starts cassandra as usual, and during start it executes `cassandra-env.sh` script that may set memory options if they aren't set in the `JVM_OPTS` environment variable, so if you start container with corresponding memory options set via `-e JVM_OPTS`..., then it should work.

But in a long run it's better to submit config files via `/config` [mount point of Docker image](https://github.com/datastax/docker-images#using-the-dse-conf-volume), and put memory option into `jvm.options` file that is loaded by `cassandra-env.sh`.

P.S. Just tried it on my machine:

```
docker run --rm -e DS_LICENSE=accept store/datastax/dse-server:5.1.5
```

Gives me following memory switches: `-Xms1995M -Xmx1995M`.

If I run it with:

```
docker run --rm -e DS_LICENSE=accept \
   -e JVM_OPTS="-Xms1024M -Xmx1024M" store/datastax/dse-server:5.1.5
```

then it gives correct `-Xms1024M -Xmx1024M`...

Comment: thank you for the response,  i tried the first option you suggested but when i set this it looks like two flags appear in the process one because of my env variable and one from the Cassandra default. regarding your second suggestion this will mean that i have to mange the Cassandra config as part of my code right?

Comment: That very strange - can you show the command that you did use to start Docker?

Comment: docker run -dit --name sdc-cs --env RELEASE="${RELEASE}" --env CS_PASSWORD="${CS_PASSWORD}" --env ENVNAME="${DEP_ENV}" --env HOST_IP=${IP} --env JVM_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m" --log-driver=json-file --log-opt max-size=100m --log-opt max-file=10 --ulimit memlock=-1:-1 --ulimit nofile=4096:100000 --volume /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro --volume ${WORKSPACE}/data/CS:/var/lib/cassandra --volume ${WORKSPACE}/data/environments:/root/chef-solo/environments --publish 9042:9042 --publish 9160:9160 ${PREFIX}/sdc-cassandra:${RELEASE} /bin/sh

Comment: PS the second option you suggested is for DST Cassandra only or is it for the OS impl as well?

Comment: The second option depends on the image - in DSE image team implemented very simple solution of linking files from multiple places into one place. For OSS version, `jvm.options` will work, but location will be different.  When you run the image, what options are shown with `ps -aef|grep cassandra` ?

Comment: I've updated the answer with actual output from `docker run`

Comment: is this for the DS image or will it work on a standerd image as well?

Comment: I think that it should work with standard image as well, but I didn't test